# What happens to candies when you transfer ALL pokemon of the same evolution line?

Tags: pokemon-go

So candies read as a total amount no matter what Pokemon you look at of the same type or evolution, for example you'll have 5 Rattatas and 5 Raticates and 30 candies in total that you see when you look at any Pokemon.

But to my knowledge there isn't really a bag for the candies themselves.

If you got rid of all but one Rattata, you would see that you would have 39 candies, but what happens to the candies if you get rid of that last Pokemon? 
Do the candies disappear with it or will they return when you catch another same-type Pokemon?

Answer (score 1):

The candies do not disappear, they're still there for the next time you catch a Pokemon from that same family. 
As far as I'm aware at the moment, the only way to see how many you have for a particular family is by looking at the page for a Pokemon from that particular family, which makes sense to me, as that information doesn't do you any good unless you have a Pokemon to use them on.